# reddit API praw error HTTP request or JSON object

Tags: python, json, reddit, praw

I use reddit API praw and psraw to extract comments from a subreddit, however, I got two errors today after running a few loops:

1. JSON object decoded error or empty -> ValueError, even I catch exception in my code, still doesnt work.
2. http request

example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../subreddit psraw.py", line 20, in <module>
    for comment in submission.comments:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\praw\models\reddit\base.py", line 31, in __getattr__
self._fetch()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\praw\models\reddit\submission.py", line 142, in _fetch
  'sort': self.comment_sort})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 367, in get
data = self.request('GET', path, params=params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 451, in request
params=params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 174, in request
params=params, url=url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 108, in _request_with_retries
data, files, json, method, params, retries, url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 93, in _make_request
params=params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\rate_limit.py", line 33, in call
response = request_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\requestor.py", line 49, in request
    raise RequestException(exc, args, kwargs)
prawcore.exceptions.RequestException: error with request 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth.reddit.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=16.0)
```

Since a subreddit contains 10k+ comments, is there a way to solve such issue? is it because reddit website has some problems today?

My code:

```
import praw, datetime, os, psraw
reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('example')

for submission in psraw.submission_search(reddit, subreddit='example', limit=1000000):

    try:
    #get comments
        for comment in submission.comments:
            subid = submission.id
            comid = comment.id
            com_body = comment.body.encode('utf-8').replace("\n", " ")
            com_date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(comment.created_utc)
            string_com = '"{0}", "{1}", "{2}"\n'
            formatted_string_com = string_com.format(comid, com_body, com_date)

            indexFile_comment = open('path' + subid + '.txt', 'a+')
            indexFile_comment.write(formatted_string_com)

    except ValueError:
        print ("error")
        pass
        continue
    except AttributeError:
        print ("error")
        pass
        continue
```

Comment: It looks like praw is timing out on authenticating with reddit (see the last line in your traceback). That could absolutely be related to site problems.

Comment: I'd second what David has said, it seems like Praw fails to authenticate with Reddit. Make sure you have the write authentication information, this would the case if it still does not work.